# Groovy/Grails date class - getting day of month

Tags: grails, groovy

Currently I'm using the following code to get year, month, day of month, hour and minute in Groovy:

```
Date now = new Date()
Integer year = now.year + 1900
Integer month = now.month + 1
Integer day = now.getAt(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) // inconsistent!
Integer hour = now.hours
Integer minute = now.minutes
// Code that uses year, month, day, hour and minute goes here
```

Using `getAt(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` for the day of the month seems a bit inconsistent in this context. Is there any shorter way to obtain the day of the month?

Comment: Why are you doing now.year + 1900?

Comment: Mykola: new Date().year is currently 109, hence the need to add 1900.

Comment: But why do you add this to some 'year' and don't use it?

Comment: year, month, day, hour and minute are used later in the code.

Comment: what about milli or micro seconds? i tried now.milliseconds or microseconds but no such property

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you add the following to your code it should assign the day of the month to the day Integer:

```
Integer day = now.date
```

Here's a stand-alone example:

```
def now = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", "2009-09-15")
assert 15 == now.date
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I could miss it!

Comment: Maybe you missed it because of the horrible API!

Answer (score 7):

Isn't all those lines are kind of garbage?
The following two lines do the job in a groovysh

```
date = new Date()
date.getAt(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

To use this at your real code and not in the console

```
def date = new Date()
def dayOfMonth = date.getAt(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Comment: This code gives me 6 at the groovysh console. If it is what you want than this is the answer.

Comment: The problem is not obtaining the day of the month. The problem is doing it in a consistent way.

Comment: the "garbage" is actually the context of the question

Answer (score 3):

You can get just the day of the month from a `Date` in Groovy like this:

```
​Date date = new Date()
int dayOfMonth = date[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you are doing it is the only way. The java date object stores the month and day, but doesn't store any information such as how long the given month is or what day of the month your on. You need to use the Calendar class to find out a lot of this info.

Answer (score 1):

This version is fairly terse:

```
Calendar.instance.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Comment: Absolutely, but compare it to the other lines. I was looking for a consistent way to do it.